# after click on edit button previous uploaded file is not showing on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Previous uploaded file/image is not showing on edit form after clicking on the edit button it shows only no file selected, but files are already stored into the database. This is my haml form which is below.

```
.....
.....

.field
  = f.label "address_proof"
  = f.file_field :address_proof, :required => true, :class =>'form- control', placeholder: "upload address proof"
.field
  = f.label "identity_proof"
  = f.file_field :identity_proof, :required => true, :class =>'form-control', placeholder: "upload identity proof" 
 %br.actions
  = f.submit 'submit', :class=>"btn waves-effect waves-light", :id=>"validate"
  = link_to 'Cancel', admin_members_path, :class=>"btn white grey-text waves-effect waves-red"
```

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to add code to show the current file name (or whatever).  Like an if/else along the lines of `<% if member.identity_proof.present? %>` or whatever the modal name is, to show the current file name if it exists, by default it shows just like you have.

Answer (score 1):

The file field, which gets translated to a `<input type="file" />` tag, can only be used to accept files from the user. It is unable to display any information about a file that exists in your app's file storage.

What you *can* do, is to show the information of the already attached file next to the input, perhaps in the label. My HAML is very rusty, so here's an example using ERB, and assuming that you use ActiveStorage:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :identity_proof do %>
    <% if f.object.identity_proof.attached? %>
      The currently attached file is <%= f.object.identity_proof.filename %>. Click here to replace this file.
    <% else %>
      No file has been uploaded yet. Please pick a file.
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.file_field :identity_proof %>
</div>
```

However, this still leaves the input tag itself, which says *No file selected* (or something similar) still visible.

One of the most common approaches to tackle this is to render the input field invisible (using CSS), and then style the label with custom CSS to make it look like an input field. Since the label is linked to the input field, clicking on it would still trigger the browser's filepicker. The input field can be hidden in a variety of ways - a common choice is to position the label over the input, and then hide the input by setting its opacity to zero.

Here's a rough example.

```css
.form-control {
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harigopal/fs4qgdo6/1/) of the above!